# Get Array of Dates for Current Month in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to generate an array of current month dates in **YYYY-MM-DD** format in jQuery.

For Example,

if the current month is August, then I want the array to be something like this

**[2018-08-01, 2018-08-02, --------- 2018-08-31]**

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all yourself yet? Please post the code you've tried

Comment: This is what I am trying to implement, But I have no idea how to work with dates? 

var result = [];
var today = new Date();
var days = daysInMonth(today.getMonth() + 1, today.getFullYear());
result = Array.from(currentDate).join(',');

Comment: If I understand, you want 12 arrays? for each month? what about the year?

Comment: The above code generates the number of days for the current month, I just want it to generate full dates instead. 

[1,2,3,4,5 ------- 31]

to 

[2018-08-01, 2018-08-02, --------- 2018-08-31]

Comment: @IsraGab no, I don't want 12 arrays. I want it to fetch the current month automatically using 

today = new Date();
today.getMonth() + 1;

and then generate an array for all the dates for the current month.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this like below:
**Edited**

```
var date = new Date();
var month = date.getMonth();
date.setDate(1);
var all_days = [];
while (date.getMonth() == month) {
    var d = date.getFullYear() + '-' + date.getMonth().toString().padStart(2, '0') + '-' + date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    all_days.push(d);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
}
console.log(all_days);
```

Comment: Thank you so much this saved me. Working perfectly (y)

Comment: thanks... if u need more help just ask :)

Comment: Can we extend above and change the output to something like this? 

From ["2018-08-01", "2018-08-02",  ----- ] 
to 
[moment("2018-08-01").format('MMMM DD'), moment("2018-08-02").format('MMMM DD'),  ---- ]

Comment: is moment() ur defined method ?

Comment: just replace this line `all_days.push(date.toISOString().split('T')[0]);` by this `all_days.push(moment(date.toISOString().split('T')[0])).format('MMMM DD'));`

Comment: I am using it for chart.js and the above format is required by its helper moment.js I don't have an in-depth idea about, I am a beginner in chart.js but I guess yes.

Comment: dnt worry, just use the line i just added in comments. if its not working please ask. w8ing for ur response :)

Comment: I tried but its giving error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: please run this hard coded line `moment("2018-08-01").format('MMMM DD');` if its not working then error in 'moment' or 'format' method

Comment: I tried like this all_days.push(moment("2018-08-01").format('MMMM DD')); and that is working generating an index array.

Array(31)
0:"August 01"
1:"August 01"
2:"August 01"

Comment: sorry boss i made a mistake :/ , use this line `all_days.push(moment(date.toISOString().split('T')[0]).format('MMMM DD'));`

Comment: Great! working now, thanks (y)

Comment: Hi, please check the output today. Don't know why but its generating dates ranging between Aug 02 - Sep 01. it should be between Aug 01- Aug 31.

Comment: please check edited, now it wont do that again. i will update you soon y this happened.

Comment: sure thanks, this seems to work.

Comment: I figure it out why its generating date ranges unexpectedly, bcoz i use `.toISOString()` that not only return our desired format 'yyyy-mm-dd' but also converts local date to ISO 8601 , that is different date, e.g in my case, date is GMT +5, if i use `.toISOString()` at 1:20 AM it will return me previous date. hope you understand. So I Edited for all countries

Comment: yes I get it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

To achieve expected result, use below option

1. Get current date of month
2. Get End date of month
3. Loop using end date of month and push to result array

```js
var today = new Date(); // current date
var end = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate(); // end date of month
var result = [];

for(let i = 1; i <= end; i++){
   result.push(today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() < 10? '0'+today.getMonth(): today.getMonth()) +'-'+ (i < 10 ? '0'+ i: i))
}

console.log(result)
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/aaoZob?editors=1010

Comment: Thank You :) Its working (Y)

Comment: Glad it is working , :)

Comment: Can you explain this part? for(let i = 1; i <= end; i++){
   result.push(today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() < 10? '0'+today.getMonth(): today.getMonth()) +'-'+ (i < 10 ? '0'+ i: i))
}  I am making a few changes.

Comment: I am formatting the date through loop as YYYY-MM-DD, and also adding 0 infront of single digit month and dates like 9 as '09'

Comment: I solved my problem after a little modification as you forget to add +1 for getMonth(), I am just curious if this is the correct way? Please see this

var thisMonth = today.getMonth() + 1; // current month
for (let i = 1; i <= endDate; i++) {
allDays.push(moment(today.getFullYear() + '-' + (thisMonth < 10 ? '0' + thisMonth : thisMonth) + '-' + (i < 10 ? '0' + i : i)).format('MMM DD'));
}

Comment: yes, adding +1 will give current month